# Traveling on a UAE work visa with an old passport number

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, dubai, uae

I have a Dubai employment visa. My passport number on this visa has the ECR category, but I've now changed my passport to the ECNR category.

Will the immigration authorities allow me to travel? This is my first time visiting Dubai on my employment visa; I earlier used a visitor's visa on my ECR passport.

Comment: Your work visa is in your old passport?

Comment: Work visas are an Expats.SE domain

Comment: @JonathanReez Says who? This is purely about travel.

Comment: @Relaxed OP has a work visa and uses that visa to travel to his place of employment. Sounds like expat territory to me unless a clarification is made (e.g. it's the Indian immigration that checks visas, then it's irrelevant if it's a work visa)

Comment: @JonathanReez It's irrelevant either way, it's about *travel* as you just wrote, there is no reason for this question to be off-topic here.

Comment: @Relaxed I disagree. Feel free to cast a reopen vote afterwards

Comment: @JonathanReez What is there to disagree about? You're making rules on the fly now? It's about entering the country and you wrote yourself it was about travelling, on what basis could it possibly be off-topic? Also +12, do we really want to be that ridiculous?

Comment: @Relaxed it's about entering UAE on a UAE work visa. It seems likely that a different set of regulations would then be triggered, which are better discussed on Expats.SE. If OP had a tourist visa it would be a different matter. Also, OP doesn't mention he's going to the UAE on vacation, so I presume he's traveling for work.

Comment: @JonathanReez Actually, I thought about mentioning in my very first comment that it was likely that the exact same rules apply to a tourist visa but that's not even relevant and neither is the intent of the OP. What's off-topic here are questions about life abroad, obtaining a long-term visa, etc. Travel, even as an expatriate, is still travel, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46866/discussion-between-jonathanreez-and-relaxed).

Answer (score 2):

No worries. You can use your new passport. Make sure to bring both passports and show both to the immigration officer as you enter Dubai.

Comment: Thank you, would you add any reference with your answer preferably a link?

Comment: I am a resident in the UAE, and have used my old passport with a new visa in order to enter.

Comment: Sorry, I means new passport with old visa in order to enter the country.